# How to login and read Gmail using Robot Framework

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, robotframework, rpa

Could you please suggest how can I access Gmail Inbox as it is restricting Robots at the time of login? For your reference, I am attaching the screenshots. I am using Robot Framework (Selenium) to automate.

[image]

P.S: I did enable the option "Less secure app access" in Google Account.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @SawitreeCha : I got a workaround. I got accessed to Gmail using IMAP and SMTP. For more details, you check the following URL https://pythoncircle.com/post/727/accessing-gmail-inbox-using-python-imaplib-module/